# TypeError: Cannot clone object '<class 'sklearn.svm._classes.SVC'>'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, gridsearchcv

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

#giving params for a linear , rbf , poly and sigmoid 
params_grid = [ { 'kernel':['linead'] , 'C':[1,10,100,1000] } ,
               { 'kernel':['rbf'] , 'gamma':[1e-3,1e-4,1e-2] , 'C':[1,10,100,1000]} ,
               { 'kernel':['poly'] , 'degree':[3,4,5,6] , 'C':[1,10,100,1000]} ,
               { 'kernel':['sigmoid'] , 'C': [1,10,100,1000] }]

svm_model = GridSearchCV(svm.SVC , params_grid , cv=10)
svm_model.fit(X,Y)
```

where X is a dataset of shape (42000, 784) and Y shape is (42000,)

`TypeError: Cannot clone object '<class 'sklearn.svm._classes.SVC'>' (type <class 'abc.ABCMeta'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.`

Comment: Try `svm.SVC()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is `svm.SVC` but according to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) it must implement the `estimator` interface.

> This is assumed to implement the scikit-learn estimator interface. Either estimator needs to provide a score function, or scoring must be passed.